# Why would I use Metamask instead of only using Web3.js in the browser?

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapp-development, dapps

It is my understanding that Metamask brings a convenient way for the user to interact with DApps by storing their wallets and by providing an interface that gives the user control of what the DApp is doing. Is this correct?

If the user does not mind at all inserting the wallet address and password, and they fully trust the app, is there any reason to use Metamask? Web3.js allows doing everything that Metamask does in the browser as well, right?

Comment: MetaMask now monitors users' IP addresses. If you substitute Metamask with web3.js to carry out all the same functions for your wallet, does web3.js also use surveillance on its users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, you are absolutely right. There are more other features of metamask please dig it.
Ok now from the side of [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html) we can do alot of wallet related work.

> web3.eth.accounts

The `web3.eth.accounts` contains functions to generate Ethereum accounts and sign transactions and data. please see other function related to account.

You can create in memory [wallet](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet) from web3js

> web3.eth.accounts.wallet - Contains an in memory wallet with multiple
>   accounts. These accounts can be used when using
>   web3.eth.sendTransaction().

Now the point is, You can create your own wallet using web3js library. You don't need metamask to

> Generate account
>    deploy contract
>     Call contract
>    Encryption
>   Decryption
>       sign Transaction

Answer (score 3):

You are right to say that you can use `web3` to build anything instead of `Metamask`.And you may not know the advantages of meta-mask in addition to using as a wallet:

- Unlock MyEtherWallet.com quick, click open
- When you visit fake sites, it will show a red alert
- Anti-stealing login key

Since you are a developer, you are only interested in logging into ethereum wallet and offering functionality. But users need an easy experience on the Dapp system. I think `Metamask` did it very well. `Vitalik Buterin` once said that one of the big challenges of Ethereum is the limited user experience, so you should keep in mind when developing your app.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. But that would defeat the point of using a decentralized, trustless application.

Comment: What is the difference between running Web3.js in the browser and using Metamask?

Comment: Metamask does all the signing of transactions, without exposing the user's private key to the website